# Constant Error Running Ruby on Rails on Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana, railsinstaller, railsinstaller-windows

I've almost pulled out all the remaining hair on my bald head. I've been tinkering with Ruby on Rails on Windows 7 and it works great. I use RailsInstaller 2.2.1 and AptanaStudio3 as my IDE on Windows 7 64bits.

However, going through similar process, I installed these two tools on my 64bit Windows 8 and all hell as been let loose for the past 3 days. RoR projects that run flawlessly on the win 7 do not run on Win 8 with Ruby 1.9.3 p392 and Rails 3.2.13.

Anytime I run launch the server with:

```
$ rails s
←[31mCould not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

And

```
$ bundle install
```

gives:

```
$ bundle install
```

Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/v
endor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in `initialize': Bad address - connect
(2) (Errno::EFAULT)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in`open'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in `block in connect'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in`timeou
t'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeou
t'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in`connect'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_s
tart'

I've uninstalled and re-installed countless times but no solution. I'm considering installing virtual machine with Win 7 since it works smoothly on Win7. But that means installing another OS.... I'd like to know if others have had success with RoR on Windows 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I myself tried using RoR on Windows 8 and could not find a solution to the issues I was running into. My suggestion is to keep with Windows 7, wait a little longer until Windows 8's bugs are sorted out.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one. I'll probably go the VM route with another Win 7 install. Thanks Pal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running rails on Win8 just fine.  I checked my rake version, and it is indeed 10.1.0.  Try doing `gem uninstall rake`, and then `gem install rake --version 10.1.0`.  Then try bundler again.

I ran into something similar what I cloned the app I was developing on win8 onto a win 7 machine.  The gemfile.lock from win8 was specifying a version of rake that win7 didn't like.

PS:  I sympathize with the hair thing.  Not much left here either.  Hard to "get a grip" some days :-)

Comment: Interesting find for me. I used the first code to uninstall all the rake versions. But the 2nd code gives this error:
    $ gem install rake --version 10.1.0
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 10.1.0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::EFAULT: Bad address - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Hmmm.  That's strange.  That's the latest version: https://rubygems.org/gems/rake.  Try it without specifying the version, and see what version you get.

Comment: I've also tried without version. Same prob. Maybe I'll go the VM route  on Win 8. Thanks D. You crack me up. Much needed at a time like this.

Comment: `gem install rake` gave you an error?  That's a more basic problem than just the version.